# Navigation Drawer closes instantly on open

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the support library and the DrawerLayout.

The app starts with the drawer open as per android guidelines.  If the drawer is closed and the user hits the back button I want the drawer to open.  I'm intercepting onKeyDown to open the drawer, but the drawer opens and closes instantly, resulting in a flicker.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerMenu)){
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerMenu);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using OnBackPressd method?

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

     if(!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerMenu)){
     drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerMenu);

    }
    else
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: I didn't realise that there was a prefered method of intercepting back, i thought the two were pretty much equal.  This works, but can you explain why? :) thanks

Comment: Well, on back pressed has his own implementation, the one you called can be also used in android keyboard..also, its might duplicate the back event if you use the way you did without overriding the onBack method. if its help, accept the answer :)